# Move all files / folder within SmartFinderFolder to destination w/ serial / single consecutive operation with AppleScript MacOS Serria

Tags: macos, file, applescript, move

**Objective:** Move all files and files in folders to destination folder and maintain the file structure [files and named folders]. Important for music files in albums.

**Functional:** Move all listed files in SmartFolder [named] to destinationFolder with serial / consecutive move operation and maintain the same file structure and copy of dataFiles listed in SmartFolder.

**Key:** All files were obtained for transfer. Normal CMD + A, CMD + C, CMD + V hangs up the computer and the transfer does not initiate. The AppleScript to move each dataObject to destinationPath is all.

**Facts:** How to reference objects [files, folders] and their proper reference format and accepted path syntax; path or POSIX, and use of alias. Basic operations. I ran an AppleScript to move filePath to pathDestination, and was otherwise successful, and would be nice to known the formalization syntax for path reference.

```
tell application "Finder"
    move allFiles to destinationFolder
    // recursive/repeat code to loop through all listed files and folder
end tell
```

**Reference:** [Applescript, show all files with tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932459/applescript-show-all-files-with-tag)
[Moving / selecting listed files from 'smartfolder' containers as active windows and displayLists. It was an alt. solution since AppleScript will not reference the SmartFolder as an object, nor will it dynamically call the listProperty of the SmartFolder object unless called by an unknown or un-reference method or command.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service! If you have code that's not working for you then have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and conform your question to it.

Answer (score 1):

Since your main issue, as far as I can tell, seems to be dealing with SmartFolders in AppleScript, which—as you said—cannot be referenced as folder objects, this little snippet might be of help:

```
    set SmartFolder to "/Users/CK/My Smart Folder.savedSearch"

    tell application "System Events" to get value of property list file SmartFolder
    set {[Scope], Query} to {SearchScopes, RawQuery} of RawQueryDict of result

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tab

    set Command to {"mdfind -onlyin", ¬
        quoted form of Scope as text, ¬
        quoted form of Query as text} as text

    set SearchResults to paragraphs of (do shell script Command)
        --> returns a list of posix files
        --> e.g. {"/Users/CK/Downloads/This is file one.txt", ...}
```

This will return a list of POSIX paths to files that match the search criteria.

I would recommend using *System Events* rather than *Finder* to deal with large numbers of files.  It can also handle posix paths without the need to manually coerce them into aliases or whatever.  So, given a posix path, such as the ones returned in the list using the above code snippet, you simply do this:

```
    set myfile to item 1 of SearchResults
    tell application "System Events" to move myfile to "/Users/CK/Desktop"
```

Without knowing more details of what your smart folder contains (since some searches could easily return a folder plus the contents of that folder, which you'd have to bear in mind when getting your AppleScript to recurse through the search results), I can't give you more than that.  But, you said your main problems were being unable to handle SmartFolders and not knowing how to reference files/folders.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using the latest version of Sierra.

Set the value of  `property moveToNewFolder`to the destination folder of your choice

This script creates a "Choose From List" Dialog, allowing you to choose any smart folder which resides on your system.  It will then move all of these files and folders in the chosen smart folder, to your set destination folder.

```
property savedSearches : (path to home folder as string) & "Library" & ":Saved Searches"
property savedSearchesSubFolders : {}
property namesOfSavedSearchesSubFolders : {}
property selectedSearchFolder : ""
property selectedSearchFolderPath : missing value
property moveTheseItems : missing value
property moveToNewFolder : (path to desktop as text) & "untitled folder" -- change this value to your preferred destination folder

tell application "Finder"
    activate
    delay 0.1 -- may need to adjust delay time value
    open savedSearches
    delay 0.1 -- may need to adjust delay time value
    reveal savedSearches
    delay 0.1 -- may need to adjust delay time value
    select savedSearches
    delay 0.1 -- may need to adjust delay time value
    set current view of Finder window 1 to column view
    delay 0.1 -- may need to adjust delay time value
    tell its Finder window (POSIX path of savedSearches)
        delay 0.1 -- may need to adjust delay time value
        set savedSearchesSubFolders to items
        set namesOfSavedSearchesSubFolders to name of items
        -- Allows to choose any smart folder from a list of all smart folders
        set selectedSearchFolder to choose from list namesOfSavedSearchesSubFolders ¬
            with title ¬
            "Smart Search Folders" with prompt ¬
            "Choose Your Folder" OK button name ¬
            "OK" cancel button name "CANCEL"
        set selectedSearchFolder to selectedSearchFolder as text
        set selectedSearchFolderPath to savedSearches & ":" & selectedSearchFolder
        set selectedSearchFolderPath to selectedSearchFolderPath as string
    end tell
    delay 0.2 -- may need to adjust delay time value
    select selectedSearchFolderPath
    tell Finder window 1
        set defaultView to current view
        set current view to list view
        delay 0.1 -- may need to adjust delay time value
        set current view to defaultView
        delay 0.5 -- may need to adjust delay time value
        tell application "System Events"
            key code 0 using command down
        end tell
    end tell
    set moveTheseItems to selection
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    set resultObject to move moveTheseItems ¬
        to moveToNewFolder ¬
        with replacing
end tell
```